# jquery trying to delete the highlighted element using keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to highlighting the element :

```
$(".ss").live({ 
    mouseenter: function () { HighLight(this) }, 
    mouseleave: function () { OffLight(this); }, 
      keypress: function () { KeyOperation(this); }
});

function HightLight(s)
{
  $(s).css({border : "1px solid red"});
}
function OffLight(s)
{
  $(s).css({border : "0"});
}
function KeyOperation(s)
{
  $(s).remove();
}
```

**KeyOperation()** function is not executing on keypress.

Here i am trying to do that when user highlight any element, and while highlighting, if he press `Delete key` , than that element should be deleted.But this is not working, can anybody tell me how can i do this?

Comment: Where is the code for `HighLight, OffLight, KeyOperation`? _"But this is not working"_ what doesn't work? you need to give a lot more detail so we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after. Hovering over any `.ss` element will add a temporary class. If the user presses key 46 at any time, items with that class will be removed. See working fiddle below.

```
// Bind to a closer parent if possible
$(document)
    .on("keyup", function(e){
        if ( e.which === 46 ) $(".removeMe").remove(); 
    })
    .on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".ss", function(f){
        $(this).toggleClass("removeMe", f.type === "mouseenter" );
    });
```

It should be clear from this example that `$.live` is no longer encouraged for event delegation. From here on use `$.on` instead.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YS7jH/2/

Comment: @gdoron No, you need only put focus on the `iframe` that JSFiddle uses. You don't need to click any of the elements. (*Just confirmed*)

Comment: FWIW, jQuery nomenclature is that `$.f` refers to the _utility_ function `$.f`, and `.f` refers to the functions that operate on jQuery objects.

Comment: @Alnitak. I didn't get your comment at all.

Comment: @gdoron i.e. he should refer to `.on` (which internally is `$.fn.on`), not `$.on`.

Comment: @gdoron Consider the two `$.each()` functions: one which is used to iterate over a jQuery object, like `$(".foo").each( handleElement )`, and the other is used to iterate over objects in general `$.each( array, handleArray )`. I believe @Alnitak is suggesting I refer to the first example as `.each`, and the later as `$.each`.

Comment: @JonathanSampson actually `.each()`, per the jQuery website.

Comment: @Alnitak I appreciate the advice. There certainly is a lot of ambiguity when you're dealing with JavaScript/jQuery. I find myself using `$.` to indicate a non-native member, to avoid giving the idea `.html` is a native JavaScript member.